# Extract altitude bands (polygon) from DEM (GeoTIFF)

Tags: qgis, raster, polygonize

I'm trying to extract altitude polygons from a DEM - 0 to 1000m, 1000 to 2000m, etc.
I'm not sure what this is called (noob question, yes I know), and can't find help that points in the right direction.

What is this operation is called, and where to go to find instructions on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Contour polygons geoprocessing tool:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bera - it is simple once you know what question to ask. Much appreciated